# Typescript. When properties are enum values, they are treated as read only

Tags: typescript

On this code:

```
enum SpeedRanges {
    slow,
    fast,
}

type SpeedHistogram = {
    [key in keyof typeof SpeedRanges]?: number;
};

const sh: SpeedHistogram = {};
sh.slow = 9;
```

I get this error:

> Cannot assign to 'slow' because it is a read-only property.(2540)

Why is it read only?

Comment: `sh[SpeedRanges.slow] = 9;` would let you move forward... Someone knowing typescript should be able to explain if the syntax actually creates named properties on an object for enums...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums in typescript are read-only which totally makes sense.
There are two possible solutions:

1. Remove the `readonly` modifier using [mapping modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers):

```
type SpeedHistogram = {
    -readonly [key in keyof typeof SpeedRanges]?: number;
};
```

However, enums contain index signature of `[x: number]: number`:

```
type SpeedHistogram = {
    [x: number]: number | undefined;
    slow?: number | undefined;
    fast?: number | undefined;
}
```

With an index signature, you can add any number key with a number value. We can remove the index signature by only taking the string keys of the enum, which can be done either by using the built-in utility type [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) or by interesting the keys with `string`, which will only take the intersection, which is equivalent to any string key:

```
type SpeedHistogram = {
  -readonly [Key in (keyof typeof SpeedRanges) & string]?: number;
};
```

2. Define a separate type for the keys of the `SpeedRanges`:

```
type SpeedRangesKeys = keyof typeof SpeedRanges;

type SpeedHistogram = {
  [Key in SpeedRangesKeys]?: number;
};
```

The reason why the separate type works are because in the OP version, the `keyof` is used inside of the mapped type which gets the property modifier (`readonly`) and applies to the property. When defining a separate type there is no context so we just get the union of all keys without any modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do the trick.

```js
enum SpeedRanges {
    slow,
    fast,
}

type SpeedRangeKey = keyof typeof SpeedRanges;

type SpeedHistogram = {
    [key in SpeedRangeKey]?: number;
};

const sh: SpeedHistogram = {};
sh.slow = 9;
```

Comment: Nice, if you can also explain why OP's variant did not work it would be awesome (to me both are equivalent - would like to know the reason)

Comment: I'd love to learn the reason myself... I totally agree, the code does look equivalent, but somehow TS treats it completely differently...

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript enums are `readonly`. When you iterate over the keys *directly* to define another keys, you also inherit the original key properties in the newly defined keys, as the `readonly` property.

If you want to remove the `readonly` property, just use `-readonly` modificator, like so:

```js
enum SpeedRanges {
    slow,
    fast,
}

type SpeedHistogram = {
    -readonly [key in keyof typeof SpeedRanges]?: number;
};

const sh: SpeedHistogram = {};
sh.slow = 9;
```

You can also use [@IgorDanchenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632155/typescript-when-properties-are-enum-values-they-are-treated-as-read-only/76632226#76632226), which is using the original key list to define a string union, which  being just a list of strings, they do not have any properties in them.

Comment: With this approach you'd be able to assign values to arbitrary integer keys (e.g., `sh[42] = 42` would be valid), which is probably not the desired outcome...

Comment: @IgorDanchenko oooohhh that's true! Good catch. I guess we need a filter in the `keyof typeof SpeedRanges` to remove the number index. Your answer is better then (upvoted), as is filtering everything but the key strings. I can't think of a way to fix this right now, and I have to go make dinner xD by the way I tried to answer the "why are they readonly?" question. You could edit your answer with the explanation and your better solution just in case someone has the same doubt.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are trying to use number enum when you want a string enum

```
enum SpeedRanges {
  slow = "slow",
  fast = "fast",
}
 
type SpeedHistogram = {
  [key in SpeedRanges]?: number;
};

const sh: SpeedHistogram = {};
sh.slow = 9;
```

Comment: This is not using the keys in the enum, but the values in the enum. Changing the enum `slow = "slow"` to `slow = "slow2"` is making `SpeedHistogram` to have a key named `slow2` instead.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Question says that "properties are enum values", not keys

Comment: oh! you are right! Can't remove the downvote if the answer is not edited... :-(

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález can you now?

Comment: yes! (Filling Minimum 15 characters)